# SQL Server 2012 Can retrieve data from overritten database?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL SERVER Management Studio 2012, I have restored the new version of my sql server database. I checked the Override checkbox on the restore popup as you can see on the image. Finally, I realised that I have lost some datas. I want to get datas of a table of the old database. Is it possible ? 
I don't have any backup of the old database.

[image]

Comment: There's no "overriden" database. Overwritten  means the backup data was written over the existing data. If you don't have a backup of that data, it's gone

Comment: And the log file ? It doesn't contains any information on the old database ?

Comment: No it does not. All of your old data is gone.